# ASP.NET MVC: Put searching attributes into url (not query string)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

have implemented filtering on my ASP.NET MVC 5 app. 
My searchbox consists of a few Dropdownlists with predefined values. When the Dropdownlist value changes, the form is submitted and I see all available tickets for a specific method.

After the form submits the page reloads and I see the url like `mysite.com/?Method=car`. But I would like to get rid of the query string and put car directly into the url, i.e. 
`mysite.com/method/car` or `mysite.com/method/plain` etc

Is it possible?

Search box

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Transfer", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Method, Model.Methods, new { @class = "query"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="hidden" />
}
```

My action method

```
[Route("~/transfer/{method?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> List(string method)
{
    //filter and displaying
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: I normally set up routes in the route config file. Do you need to add '?' in {method?} when setting it up as an attribute?

Comment: Yes I need. "method" not declared as optional in Routing settings as optional. SO I should declare it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `Html.BeginForm` with `FormMethod.Get` will serialize all the form values into query string. So if you want friendly URLs you will have to write some JavaScript (jQuery in this example).

First of all you can remove the form

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Method, Model.Methods, new { @class = "query"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button type="button" id="submitMethodBtn">Submit</button>

<script>
   var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Search", "Transfer")/'
   $('#submitMethodBtn').click(function(){
       var url = baseUrl + $(#'@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Method)').val();
       window.location.href = url;
   })
</script>
```

**Some issues/clarifications:**

**1**if you enter `mysite.com/method/car` (assuming that issue #2 is resolved )in browser it will take you to a correct action so your issue is basically generating friendly Url in the view.

**2** In the provided code example i used an inline script. You can extract it to a separate static file but you will have to hard-code the url and the html id for Method property.

**3** Your action method gets int as parameter so how do you expect it to work with `mysite.com/method/car` (car is a string) ?

Comment: thanks! on 3. right, I use int tight now in project, but for this sample used slug, so missed that changes.. Fixed it in sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can call an ajax method on page which will avoid query string and when controller redirects to ActionResult then again you can call ajax method on redirected page. By this way you can avoid query string in MVC.
Take below code as example.

```
$.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
      url: "Transfer/search",  
      data: "{ID:1}",  
      dataType: "json",  
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
 });
```

Make return type as JsonResult of controller method.

Comment: yeah. but this approach isn't good for SEO. That's why I need user-friendly url